# Finding '_' without treating it as a wild character

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, query, table

Does anyone know how to select records containing an underscore without the query treating it as a wild character?

For instance, I'm trying to select records in a text field ending with '_' to then right trim the underscore off the record.

Comment: What query language are you using to perform your trim?  SQL, Python, VB Script, etc.?

Comment: SQL to select the records.  For the trim I will use a string function from VB Script.

Comment: Are you using the SQL query to select records that have the underscore at the end, or are you filtering by some other criteria?  Also, do your field entries have underscores contained elsewhere in the string, or only at the end?

Comment: SQL to select records.  I'm trying to select records all records that are literally 'MH_' at the end but I also have records like 'MHA', 'MHB', 'MHC", etc..  I'm not trying to select the 'MHA' or 'MHB'.  The records I'm looking for would only have underscores at the end but '%MH_' is returning anything after the MH.

Comment: If you are only using the SQL query to select records that you are trying to remove the underscore on, then I would use VB Script's Replace() function.  You can also use Python's .rstrip or .strip function to remove the underscore.  In either case, you don't need to perform a SQL query, because the function will only remove the underscores.  Saves you a step.

Answer (score 4):

Include two '_' in the where Clause followed by the ESCAPE keyword and character.
Fieldname like '%__%' escape '_'
Please see "SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS"